# How to use Java Enums being DRY with only a single parameter different between instantiations?

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to figure out if there is a clean way of doing this.  I want to design an ENUM to maintain a list of constant values for different components in my application.  Each enum would have the same configuration and same parameters, but would differ at the very least by component name.

In a normal Java class, I could build all the basic logic/code in a base abstract class, and have each component constants extend the abstract class and populate only its own pertinent information.  However, Java enums do not allow extending existing classes.

Is there something I can do to avoid having to either push all my constants in a single Enum (ugggg!) or recreate the same enum class each time for each differing component?  Definitely not DRY in that case, but I do not know how to avoid the issue.

For a quick use-case example off the top of my head.  Say I want to keep a list of all my request mappings in an Enum for use elsewhere in my application.  Fairly easy to design an enum that says:

```
public enum RequestMapping {
    INDEX("index"),
    GET_ALL_USERS( "getAllUsers");

    private String requestMapping = "/users";
    private String path;

    RatesURI( String path ){
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getRequestMapping(){
        return requestMapping;
    }

    public String getPath(){
        return path;
    }

    public String getFullRequestPath(){
        return requestMapping + "/" + path;
    }
}
```

It becomes easy to use RequestMapping.GET_ALL_USERS.getFullRequestPath().

Now if I want to create this enum on a per-controller basis, I would have to recreate the entire Enum class and change the "requestMapping" value for each one.  Granted, this enum has nearly no code in it, so duplicating it would not be difficult, but the concept still remains.  The theoretical "clean" way of doing this would be to have an abstract AbstractRequestMapping type that contained all the methods, including an abstract getRequestMapping() method, and only have the extending Enums implement the controller-specific getReqeuestMapping().  Of course, since Enums cannot be extended, I can't think of a non DRY way of doing this.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on what you mean by _ENUM to maintian a list of constant values_? Is it only component name that differ, or other stuff? Maybe a brief usecase/example will answer those questions.

Comment: @SnakeDoc DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: @Bittenus - I just tried updating with a very simple/basic use-case scenario.

Comment: DUE - dont use enum (for everything). start with a normal class and static final fields.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered extending a class that takes `Enum` as a generic parameter? It is an amazingly flexible mechanism.

```
public class Entity<E extends Enum<E> & Entity.IE> {
  // Set of all possible entries.
  // Backed by an EnumSet so we have all the efficiency implied along with a defined order.
  private final Set<E> all;

  public Entity(Class<E> e) {
    // Make a set of them.
    this.all = Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.<E>allOf(e));
  }

  // Demonstration.
  public E[] values() {
    // Make a new one every time - like Enum.values.
    E[] values = makeTArray(all.size());
    int i = 0;
    for (E it : all) {
      values[i++] = it;
    }
    return values;
  }

  // Trick to make a T[] of any length.
  // Do not pass any parameter for `dummy`.
  // public because this is potentially re-useable.
  public static <T> T[] makeTArray(int length, T... dummy) {
    return Arrays.copyOf(dummy, length);
  }

  // Example interface to implement.
  public interface IE {
    @Override
    public String toString();

  }

}

class Thing extends Entity<Thing.Stuff> {

  public Thing() {
    super(Stuff.class);
  }

  enum Stuff implements Entity.IE {
    One,
    Two;

  }
}
```

You can pass the nature of your implementation up to the parent class in many different ways - I use `enum.class` for simplicity.

You can even make the `enum` implement an interface as you can see.

The `values` method is for demonstration only. Once you have access to the `Set<E>` in the parent class you can provide all sorts of functionality just by extending `Entity`.

Answer (score 1):

I will probably split the responsibilities into two parts:

1. Logic about how a request is structured, and put that into an **immutable** class.
2. Actual configurations of each request, stored in enums

The enum will then store an instance of that class, you can add new methods to the class, without modifying the different enums, as long as the constructor remains the same. Note that the class **must** be immutable, or your enum will not have a constant value.

You can use it like the:

```
ServiceRequest.INDEX.getRequest().getFullRequestPath()
```

With these classes:

```
public interface RequestType {
  Request getRequest();
}
public class Request {
    private final String requestMapping;
    private final String path;

    RatesURI(String requestMapping, String path){
        this.requestMappint = requestMapping;
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getRequestMapping(){
        return requestMapping;
    }

    public String getPath(){
        return path;
    }

    public String getFullRequestPath(){
        return requestMapping + "/" + path;
    }
}

public enum ServiceRequest implements RequestType {
    INDEX("index"),
    GET_ALL_USERS( "getAllUsers");

    private final Request;

    ServiceRequest(String path) {
        request = new Request("users/", path)
    }

    public String getRequest{
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Creative / Interesting approach.  Of course, for every ServiceRequest1, ServiceRequest2, ServiceRequest3 enums which implement RequestType, you will still find yourself repeating the "getRequest()" implementation, so not a completely DRY, but very close.

Comment: You could nix the interface, make the `Request` a public field and call it `_`. Then you only have to type two extra characters and they aren't letters. `ServiceRequest.INDEX._.getPath();` is pretty DRY. (For anyone not sure, I'm kidding.)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should be asking yourself is really *why* you want to use enums for this. First we can review some of the points that make Java *enumerated types* what they are.

### Specifically

- A Java `enum` is a class that extends `java.lang.Enum`.
- Enum constants are static final instances of that class.

There is some special syntax to use them but that is all they boil down to. Because instantiating new Enum instances is disallowed outside of the special syntax (even with reflection, enum types return zero constructors) the following is also ensured to be true:

- They can *only* be instantiated as *static final members* of the enclosing class.
- The instances are therefore *explicitly constant*.
- As a bonus, they are switchable.

What it really boils down to is what it is about the enums that makes them preferable over a simpler OOP design here. One can easily create a simple RequestMapping class:

```
/* compacted to save space */
public class RequestMapping {
    private final String mapping, path;

    public RequestMapping(String mapping, String path) {
        this.mapping = mapping; this.path = path;
    }

    public String getMapping() {
        return mapping; }
    public String getPath() {
        return path; }
    public String getFullRequestPath() {
        return mapping + "/" + path;
    }
}
```

Which can easily be extended to break down the repeated code:

```
public class UserMapping extends RequestMapping {
    public UserMapping(String path) {
        super("/users", path);
    }
}

/* where ever appropriate for the constants to appear */
public static final RequestMapping INDEX = new UserMapping("index"),
                           GET_ALL_USERS = new UserMapping("getAllUsers");
```

But I assume there is something about enums that is attractive to your design, such as the principle that instances of them are highly controlled. Enums cannot be created all willy-nilly like the above class can be. Perhaps it's important that there be no plausible way for spurious instances to be created. Of course anybody can come by and write in an enum with an invalid path but you can be pretty sure nobody will do it "by accident".

Following the Java "static instances of the outer class" enum design, an access modifier structure can be devised that generally abides by the same rule set as Enum. There are, however, two problems which we can't get around easily.

### Two Problems

- Protected modifier allows package access.

This can easily be surmounted initially by putting the Enum-analog in its own package. The problem becomes what to do when extending. Classes in the same package of the *extended class* will be able to access constructors again potentially anywhere.

Working with this depends on how stringent you want to be on creating new instances and, conversely, how clear the design ends up. Can't be a whole mess of scopes just so *only a few places* can do the wrong thing.

- Static members are not polymorphic.

Enum surmounts this by *not being extendable*. Enum types have a static method `values` that appears "inherited" because the compiler inserts it for you. Being polymorphic, DRY and having some static features means you need instances of the subtype.

Defeating these two issues depends on how stringent you want your design to be and, conversely, how readable and stable you want your implementation to be. Trying to defy OOP principles will get you a design that's hard to break but totally explodes when you call that one method in a way you aren't supposed to (and can't prevent).

### First Solution

This is almost identical to the Java enum model but can be extended:

```
/* 'M' is for 'Mapping' */
public abstract class ReturnMapping<M extends ReturnMapping> {

    /* ridiculously long HashMap typing */
    private static final HashMap <Class<? extends ReturnMapping>, List<ReturnMapping>>
                VALUES = new HashMap<Class<? extends ReturnMapping>, List<ReturnMapping>>();

    private final String mapping, path;

    protected Mapping(String mapping, String path) {
        this.mapping = mapping;
        this.path = path;

        List vals = VALUES.get(getClass());

        if (vals == null) {
            vals = new ArrayList<M>(2);
            VALUES.put(getClass(), vals);
        }

        vals.add(this);
    }

    /* ~~ field getters here, make them final ~~ */

    protected static <M extends ReturnMapping> List<M>(Class<M> rm) {
        if (rm == ReturnMapping.class) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "ReturnMapping.class is abstract");
        }
    
        List<M> vals = (List<M>)VALUES.get(rm);
    
        if (vals == null) {
            vals = new ArrayList<M>(2);
            VALUES.put(rm, (List)vals);
        }
    
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(vals);
    }
}
```

Now extending it:

```
public final class UserMapping extends ReturnMapping<UserMapping> {
    public static final UserMapping INDEX = new UserMapping("index");
    public static final UserMapping GET_ALL_USERS = new UserMapping("getAllUsers");

    private UserMapping(String path) {
        super("/users", path);
    }

    public static List<UserMapping> values() {
        return values(UserMapping.class);
    }
}
```

The huge static HashMap allows almost all of the `values` work to be done statically in the superclass. Since static members are not properly inherited this is the closest you can get to maintaining a list of values without doing it in the subclass.

Note there are two problems with the Map. The first is that you can call the `values` with `ReturnMapping.class`. The map should not contain that key (the class is abstract and the map is only added to in the constructor) so something needs to be done about it. Instead of throwing an exception you could also insert a "dummy" empty list for that key.

The other problem is that you can call `values` on the superclass before the instances of the subclass are instantiated. The HashMap will return null if this is done before the subclass is accessed. Static problem!

There is one other major problem with this design because the class can be instantiated externally. If it's a nested class, the outer class has private access. You can also extend it and make the constructor public. That leads to design #2.

### Second Solution

In this model the constants are an inner class and the outer class is a factory for retrieving new constants.

```
/* no more generics--the constants are all the same type */
public abstract class ReturnMapping {

    /* still need this HashMap if we want to manage our values in the super */
    private static final HashMap <Class<? extends ReturnMapping>, List<Value>>
                VALUES = new HashMap<Class<? extends ReturnMapping>, List<Value>>();

    public ReturnMapping() {
        if (!VALUES.containsKey(getClass())) {
            VALUES.put(getClass(), new ArrayList<Value>(2));
        }
    }

    public final List<Value> values() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(VALUES.get(getClass()));
    }

    protected final Value newValue(String mapping, String path) {
        return new Value(getClass(), mapping, path);
    }

    public final class Value {
        private final String mapping, path;

        private Value(
                    Class type,
                    String mapping,
                    String path) {

            this.mapping = mapping;
            this.path = path;

            VALUES.get(type).add(this);
        }

        /* ~~ final class, field getters need not be ~~ */
    }
}
```

Extending it:

```
public class UserMapping extends ReturnMapping {
    public static final Value INDEX, GET_ALL_USERS;

    static {
        UserMapping factory = new UserMapping();

        INDEX = factory.newValue("/users", "index");
        GET_ALL_USERS = factory.newValue("/users", "getAllUsers");
    }
}
```

The factory model is nice because it solves two problems:

- Instances can only be created from within the extending class.

Anybody can create a new factory but only the class itself can access the `newValue` method. The constructor for `Value` is private so new constants can only be created by using this method.

- `new UserMapping().values()` forces the values to be instantiated before returning them.

No more potential errors in this regard. And the ReturnMapping class is empty and instantiating new objects in Java is fast so I wouldn't worry about overhead. You can also easily create a static field for the list or add static methods such as in solution #1 (though this would deflate the design's uniformity).

There are a couple of downsides:

- Can't return the subtyped `values` List.

Now that the constant values are not extended they are all the same class. Can't dip in to generics to return differently-typed Lists.

- Can't easily distinguish what subtype a `Value` is a constant of.

But it's true this could be programmed in. You could add the owning class as a field. Still shaky.

### Sum Of It

Bells and whistles can be added to both of these solutions, for example overriding `toString` so it returns the name of the instance. Java's enum does that for you but one of the first things I personally do is override this behavior so it returns something more meaningful (and formatted).

Both of these designs provide more encapsulation than a regular abstract class and most importantly are far more flexible than Enum. Trying to use Enum for polymorphism is an OOP square peg in a round hole. Less polymorphism is the price to pay for having enumerated types in Java.